android - print log when api called
I would like to add code in unit test to print a log when the api being called.
I try below code, it print the log correctly, but when verify the size, it is 0 instead of 2.
    @Spy List<String> spyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Test
    public void verifySpyList2() {
        doAnswer(m -> {
            System.out.println(">>>> add(" + m.getArgument(0) + ")");
            return true;
        }).when(spyList).add(anyString());

        spyList.add("one");
        spyList.add("two");
        
        verify(spyList,times(1)).add("one");
        verify(spyList,times(1)).add("two");
        assertEquals(2,spyList.size());
    }

Output:
>>>> add(one)
>>>> add(two)

Expected :2
Actual   :0

Looks like when I spy on the add api to print log, then the real api call has been ignored.
How can I spy the api and call the real api call as well?
